# Passing additional form values with jQuery-populated select box

Tags: jquery, forms

Sorry for the awkward post title - I wasn't sure quite how to word it.

I have a form where the user is asked to select his favorite store location.  There are 3 select boxes with City, State, and Street Address values. I was able to use code I found on another post to set up the form so when the user selects a state, only the cities in that state are displayed, and once a city is selected, only the stores in that city are displayed.  That part is working perfectly.

However, I also need to pass 2 more values, Store Number and Region ID, based on the store selected. I have fiddled around with the script for hours on end and cannot figure out how to assign and pass through the additional values. I am new to jQuery and still can't completely identify what each function is doing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is a sample of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('select#FavState').change(function (e) {
    var cityOptions = getCityOptions($(this).val());
    $('select#FavCity').html(''); // clear the existing options
    $.each(cityOptions, function (i, o) {
        $('<option>' + o + '</option>').appendTo('select#FavCity');
    });
});
$('select#FavCity').change(function (e) {
    var streetOptions = getStreetOptions($(this).val());
    $('select#FavStreet').html(''); // clear the existing options
    $.each(streetOptions, function (i, o) {
        $('<option>' + o + '</option>').appendTo('select#FavStreet');
    });
});

 function getCityOptions(val) {
    if (val == '0') return ['Select City'];
    if (val == 'CT') return ['Avon', 'Bridgeport', 'Bristol', 'Cromwell', 'Danbury', 'Darien', 'East Windsor', 'Enfield', 'Hartford', 'Manchester', 'Milford', 'Mystic', 'Naugatuck', 'Newington', 'North Haven', 'Norwich', 'Plainville', 'Southbury', 'Southington', 'Unionville', 'Vernon', 'Waterbury', 'Wethersfield', 'Willimantic', 'Windsor Locks'];
    if (val == 'DE') return ['Dover', 'Hockessin', 'Middletown', 'Newark', 'Rehoboth Beach', 'Seaford', 'Wilmington'];

}

function getStreetOptions(val) {
    if (val == '0') return ['Select Street'];
    if (val == 'Avon') return ['347 West Main Street'];
    if (val == 'Bridgeport') return ['4545 North Main Street'];
    if (val == 'Bristol') return ['240 Buckland Street'];
    if (val == 'Cromwell') return ['48 Berlin Road'];
 }

});
</script>
```

And the select fields on the form:

```
<form>
<select name="FavState" id="FavState">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select State</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
</select>
<select name="FavStreet" id="FavStreet" class="formFields longSelectLists">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select Street</option>
</select>
<input name="StoreNumber" id="StoreNumber" type="hidden" />
<input name="RegionID" id="RegionID" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

I tried adding this to the getStreetOptions function:

```
 if (val == 'Avon') return ['347 West Main Street'];
        $('input#StoreNumber').val('4239');
        $('input#RegionID]').val('6');
```

but I figure I need to add a function within that so there's some kind of trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in the form of an object

```
var address = {};

if( val == 'Avon') {

   address["street"] = ['347 West Main Street'];
   address["StoreNumber"] = 4239;
   address["region"] = 6;
}

return address;
```

Then use the address object and display them in the corresponding fields.

You can try this code.. It can be re factored though

```
// Store the info in the form of nested objects so that it is easier to retrieve and change
var city = {
    '0': ['Not Available'],
        'CT': ['Avon', 'Bridgeport', 'Bristol', 'Cromwell', 'Danbury', 'Darien', 'East Windsor', 'Enfield', 'Hartford', 'Manchester', 'Milford', 'Mystic', 'Naugatuck', 'Newington', 'North Haven', 'Norwich', 'Plainville', 'Southbury', 'Southington', 'Unionville', 'Vernon', 'Waterbury', 'Wethersfield', 'Willimantic', 'Windsor Locks'],
        'DE': ['Dover', 'Hockessin', 'Middletown', 'Newark', 'Rehoboth Beach', 'Seaford', 'Wilmington']
}, street = {
    '0': {
        'address': ['Not Available'],
            'StoreNumber': 0,
            'RegionID': 0
    },
        'Avon': {
        'address': ['347 West Main Street'],
            'StoreNumber': 4239,
            'RegionID': 7
    },
        'Bridgeport': {
        'address': ['4545 North Main Street'],
            'StoreNumber': 5656,
            'RegionID': 12
    },
        'Bristol': {
        'address': ['240 Buckland Street'],
            'StoreNumber': 8976,
            'RegionID': 123
    },
        'Cromwell': {
        'address': ['48 Berlin Road'],
            'StoreNumber': 8976,
            'RegionID': 123
    }
};

// Cache your selectors so that you walk the DOM only once
var $favState = $('#FavState'),
    $favCity = $('#FavCity'),
    $favStreet = $('#FavStreet'), 
    $storeInput = $('#StoreNumber'),
    $regionInput = $('#RegionID');


$(document).ready(function () {
    $favState.change(function (e) {
        var value = this.value;
        // Access the object like city['CT'] .. That gives the Array
        city[value] !== undefined ? city[value] : '0';
        var cityOptions = city[value];
        $favCity.html(''); // clear the existing options
        $.each(cityOptions, function (i, o) {
            $('<option>' + o + '</option>').appendTo('#FavCity');
        });
    });

    $favCity.change(function (e) {
         var value = this.value;
        // Access the object like street['Avon'] .. That gives an object

        value = street[value] !== undefined ? value : '0';
        // This returns array
        var streetOptions = street[value].address,
            storeNumber = street[value].StoreNumber,
            regionID =street[value].RegionID;

        $favStreet.html(''); // clear the existing options
        $.each(streetOptions, function (i, o) {
            $('<option>' + o + '</option>').appendTo('#FavStreet');
        });

        // Storing the values in Hidden fields
        $storeInput.val(storeNumber);
        $regionInput.val(regionID);

        console.log('Address - ' + $favStreet.val() + 
                    ' :: Store -' + $storeInput.val() +
                    ' :: Region - ' + $regionInput.val() );
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnxTb/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, Sushanth - that's perfect. However, now I can't figure out how to split up the properties to populate the input fields. I read some posts on how to iterate through and display object properties, but still am not sure how to go about it.  Could you possibly give me an example?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sushanth - you are amazing! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it all to me. It makes much more sense now, and I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Now that I've worked with the code a bit, I have two more questions.  Some cities have more than one store. I tried adding another address, store number and region id group under the city, but only the second entry displayed.

Also, some city names exist in multiple states.  Previously I had identified them like this:
 if ((val == 'Dover') && ($("#FavState").val() == 'DE')) return ['318 North Dupont Highway'];
but I'm unsure how to do the same with the new code.

Comment: If you are expecting to have more stores then that should be an array as well instead of just a number